# Pseudospin in Graphene

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, graphene

According to my understanding, since the honeycomb lattice is not a Bravais lattice, we consider it a superposition of two lattices (say A and B). The spinor wavefunction $\begin{bmatrix}\psi_1\\ \psi_2\end{bmatrix}$ tells us that the quasiparticle is in a superposition of lattice A and B. Hence according to me, $\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ means that quasiparticle is in lattice A and$\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ is in lattice B. But I was told that this is not the exact meaning of pseudospin?

Hence, I want to know what is exactly meant by pseudospin? Also, is it called "pseudospin" because the mathematics comes out to be similar to that of spin?

I don't have any exposure of group theory and would prefer an answer free from that jargon.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the intro paragraph of [this paper](https://spj.sciencemag.org/journals/research/2019/3054062/):

> [...] the wave function can be expressed in the form of a two-component
> spinor due to the two sublattice degrees of freedom in
> graphene. As such, graphene is called a “pseudospin-1/2” system. We
> note that the spin here is not the intrinsic spin of electrons, but a
> pseudospin referring to the spatial degree of freedom of the wave
> function.

First of all you are right, the honeycomb lattice is *not* a Bravais lattice, because not all the points are equivalent (red and green arrows below). You can break it down into two triangular lattices $A$ and $B$ (blue and red dots below) which are Bravais lattices.

[image]

The basis of the two-component spinor $(\psi_1, \psi_2)$ is $(A,B)$.

Because $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are the "same" (mathematically) as spin-up and spin-down, you can do the same kind of maths as if this were actually a spin. But physically, it is *not* the intrinsic spin of the particle of quasiparticle, it's just a spatial degree of freedom.

Comment: Finally you are a moderator. I not forget. Many compliments